# hiltViewModel() not working for injecting viewModel into a compose function

Tags: kotlin, dependency-injection, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt, android-jetpack-navigation

The composable function in which I am trying to use the hiltViewModel() function

```
@Composable
fun PokedexEntry(
    entry: PokedexListEntry,
    navController: NavController,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: PokemonListViewModel = hiltViewModel()
)
```

View Model class

```
@HiltViewModel
class PokemonListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: PokemonRepository
): ViewModel() {
    fun calcDominantColor(drawable: Drawable, onFinish: (Color) -> Unit){
        val bmp = (drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)

        Palette.from(bmp).generate {palette ->
            palette?.dominantSwatch?.rgb?.let {colorValue ->
                onFinish(Color(colorValue))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp").version("1.6.10-1.0.4")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.company.pokedexapp"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.company.pokedexapp"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}


dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")

    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.7.0")

    implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0")

    implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.15.0")
    ksp("com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.15.0")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.3")

    val nav_version = "2.7.7"

    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_version")


    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil:2.6.0")


    implementation ("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44")
    kapt ("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.44")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03")
    kapt ("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.2.0")
    implementation ("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-fragment:1.0.0")

    implementation ("androidx.palette:palette-ktx:1.0.0")

    implementation ("com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1")

}
kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}
```

I am trying to use hiltViewModel() function but it shows unresolved reference and when I tried to write the import statement on my own i.e "import androidx.hilt.navigation.compose.hiltViewModel", I am not able to import it as it also shows error on androidx.hilt only. That means there is a problem with the import line but I have added all the necessary dependencies I could I think. Anyone who knows please help. Also please check the dependencies I have added.

Comment: I hope you are using this `import androidx.hilt.navigation.compose.hiltViewModel`.
Can you try using same version of hilt-compiler and hilt-navigation-compose once? 
Also just try to build anyway once you are sure you have used right imports and deps, the ide sometimes shows false errors.

Comment: What do you need `kapt ("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.2.0")` for?

Comment: @Leviathan I added it after hiltViewModel() was not working at the first attempt but it also didn't helped

Comment: @SusheelKaram no it didn't worked. Also I tried to build anyway but it gives error as I am not able to access androidx.hilt in the import line. I can do dagger.hilt but not androidx.hilt